# Excel index row

Tags: excel

I have unmatched data with missing rows in excel that i need to match. 
Column A contains distinct sample names which match those in Column C. Column C has all of the samples and Column A has only those samples with an observation. Column B has the observations corresponding to Column A. In Column D I need to put the observations in Column B which correspond to the sample in Column C OR 0 (if there was no observation, which is indicating for the sample not being present in Column A).

Example:

```
A    B    C    D
C2   8    C1   0
C4   10   C2   8
C5   1    C3   0
C9   5    C4   10
          C5   1
          C6   0
          C7   0
          C8   0
          C9   5
```

How can I create Column D? Thanks!

Comment: `vlookup` and `if` statement?

Answer (score 2):

You can start with this formula in cell `D1` and fill down.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C1,$A$1:$B$4,2,FALSE),0)
```

The `VLOOKUP` looks at the value in cell `C1` and checks the left column of the table in cells A1:B4 for a match.  If one is found, the value in the 2nd column corresponding to the match is returned, if a match is not found, a `#N/A` error is returned.

That is where the `IFERROR` formula comes in.  If an error is detected in the formula (which means no value was found), then it fills in a 0.

Answer (score 1):

Place the following in cell `D1` and drag-down:

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C1, $A$1:$B$4, 2, FALSE), 0))`

Answer (score 1):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$C$9,MATCH(C1,$A$1:$A$9,0),2),0)
```

I'm a fan of the index match match method, instead of vlookups. It allows you to grab basically anything in a defined array, by finding the row and column in the data set and giving you whats in that cell.

The index is your data (A1:C9)

The first match returns the row the data is in ( basically find whats in cell C1 in the A column)

Since we know its in Col 2 of the data I just put 2, but you could use another match to find a column header (customer #, date, part # etc)